# Pandas DateTime Conversions with Math Between Column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame of various columns: Two columns I have are 'Date of birth' and 'Date of murder'.

Date of birth looks like :
    [image]

Date of murder looks like : 
    [image]

I would like to be able to subtract each row from the DOB column from the DOM column so I can get how old someone was when they committed murder. Is there any way to go about this? 
Now it appears to be working (mostly). I made the following edits:

```
df_1['Date of birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['Date of birth'], 
  errors 
  = 
  'coerce')
  df_1['Date of Murder revised'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['Date of 
  Murder 
  revised'], errors = 'coerce')
  df_1['Date at Murder'] = (df_1['Date of birth'] - df_1['Date of 
  Murder 
  revised']) 
  print(df_1['Date at Murder'].head(10))
```

This gives m the following output:
    0   -12395 days
    1    -9941 days
    2    -7651 days
    3           NaT
    4    -9313 days
    5    -9184 days

```
I would however like to get years, but when I do the same code above 
like so:

df_1['Date at Murder'] = (df_1['Date of birth'] - df_1['Date of 
Murder revised']) / 365.25

I get this output: 
0   -34 days +01:32:38.932238
1   -28 days +18:47:33.388090
2   -21 days +01:15:53.593429
3                         NaT
4   -26 days +12:03:26.981519
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If DOM and DOB are datetime type then this should do the job:

```
df['Age'] = df.DOM - df.DOB
```

If the data type is not datetime then, convert them by

```
df.DOM = pandas.to_datetime(df.DOM)
df.DOB = pandas.to_datetime(df.DOB)
df['Age'] = (df.DOM - df.DOB).dt.days/365.25
```

Comment: thank you for responding. the problem is I get the following Traceback error despite having already converted both columns to datetime objects.                          TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @bullybear17 this error means that columns are still strings and not datetime. Could you please  check the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: It says both columns are Objects - which confuses me because I thought date_of_birth = pd.to_datetime(date_of_birth, errors='coerce') would have fixed that

Comment: Could you please add your code to the question. It will help finding out the issue.

Comment: also if i include '.days' I get a AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183507/discussion-between-pankaj-joshi-and-bullybear17).